# My selector isn't working

Tags: css

So I've got a selector like this:

```
.page-admin-settings-banner-image input[type=radio]
```

This is the body and classes:

```
<body class="not-front logged-in one-sidebar sidebar-left page-admin-settings-banner-image section-admin admin-menu">
```

This is the form and classes:

```
<form action="/admin/settings/banner-image" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" id="banner-image-select">
```

And this is the input button (I am trying to select all of the input buttons inside this form, so I can't just select the id, sadly):

```
<input type="radio" id="edit-banner-image-season-files/banners/banner-summer.jpg" name="banner_image_season" value="files/banners/banner_summer.jpg" checked="checked" class="form-radio">
```

Now, I've tried to grab this particular input in multiple ways - I've tried .form-radio, I've tried putting a path, but for some reason I just can't seem to select it. Nothing seems to be overriding the CSS I'm writing - it doesn't seem to be applied at all.

Why is this CSS:

```
.page-admin-settings-banner-image input[type=radio]{
  float: left;
  margin-top:80px;
}
```

Not working?

Or this:

```
#banner-image-select input[type=radio]{
  float: left;
  margin-top:80px;
}
```

It seems to me that the input of type radio is inside both of these elements, and it should select it.

Form HTML as per request:

```
<form action="/admin/settings/banner-image" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" id="banner-image-select">
<div><div class="form-item">
 <label>Choose a Season: </label>
 <div class="description">Choose a season for display at the top of the page</div>
 <div class="form-radios"><div class="form-item" id="edit-banner-image-season-files/banners/banner-fall.jpg-wrapper">
 <label class="option" for="edit-banner-image-season-files/banners/banner-fall.jpg"><input type="radio" id="edit-banner-image-season-files/banners/banner-fall.jpg" name="banner_image_season" value="files/banners/banner_fall.jpg" class="form-radio"> <img src="http://domain/files/banners/banner_fall.jpg"></label>
</div>
<div class="form-item" id="edit-banner-image-season-files/banners/banner-spring.jpg-wrapper">
 <label class="option" for="edit-banner-image-season-files/banners/banner-spring.jpg"><input type="radio" id="edit-banner-image-season-files/banners/banner-spring.jpg" name="banner_image_season" value="files/banners/banner_spring.jpg" class="form-radio"> <img src="http://domain/files/banners/banner_spring.jpg"></label>
</div>
<div class="form-item" id="edit-banner-image-season-files/banners/banner-summer.jpg-wrapper">
 <label class="option" for="edit-banner-image-season-files/banners/banner-summer.jpg"><input type="radio" id="edit-banner-image-season-files/banners/banner-summer.jpg" name="banner_image_season" value="files/banners/banner_summer.jpg" checked="checked" class="form-radio"> <img src="http://domain/files/banners/banner_summer.jpg"></label>
</div>
<div class="form-item" id="edit-banner-image-season-files/banners/banner-winter.jpg-wrapper">
 <label class="option" for="edit-banner-image-season-files/banners/banner-winter.jpg"><input type="radio" id="edit-banner-image-season-files/banners/banner-winter.jpg" name="banner_image_season" value="files/banners/banner_winter.jpg" class="form-radio"> <img src="http://domain/files/banners/banner_winter.jpg"></label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="op" id="edit-submit" value="Save" class="form-submit">
<input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" id="form-ed7f4579756fea75b4eae351bacd6cc3" value="form-ed7f4579756fea75b4eae351bacd6cc3">
<input type="hidden" name="form_token" id="edit-banner-image-select-form-token" value="c93ad83537dbd1252d5fc1ef5fcd91aa">
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" id="edit-banner-image-select" value="banner_image_select">

</div></form>
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your selector...

Comment: Works fine [here](http://jsbin.com/jonuqivapawo/1/edit?html,output). The code you have provided is insufficient to reproduce your problem.

Comment: please share a jsfiddle.

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm seeing a certain behavior, and I've fairly rigorously documented what I've been trying and my code examples.

Comment: What browser are you using? The CSS and HTML are fine, the issue is probably that you are using an old outdated browser (ie7?) or that your CSS file is not included in the page. Have you got your link pointing to the correct location?

Comment: I'm using Chrome, the latest version. The CSS file is absolutely included in the page - it's styling just about everything else, and I've already made changes today that were immediately reflected.

Comment: Can you share the html? The only thing I can imagine is that you are closing the form before that radio button somewhere.

Comment: The form is generated by Drupal, so I highly suspect that is not the case, but yes, I will share the form.

Comment: I cannot see why this wouldn't work. The only extra thing I'd try is this `input[type="radio"]` I know it technically doesn't matter about the quotes, but it wouldn't hurt to put them in.